# Using Ngram to Choose an Antonym

Tags: antonyms

I'm looking at using Google's Ngram to pick out the word that is the closest to an opposite of a given word by looking at the frequency and correlation over time of the two words.  For example, I predicted and found large and small have similar frequencies and appear positively correlated, and so do huge and tiny.  Nevertheless, a careful reading of the descriptions of words from a dictionary is still likely to be the best way of finding an opposite.

What suggestions does everyone have for refining this approach?  What concerns of potential pitfalls to this approach are there?

[image: opposites]

Comment: That's an interesting idea and curious result. It's also prime example of a "Not a Real Question" candidate...

Comment: @SF. I'm new to this site.  Would you mind pointing me to where I can go to read about why my question isn't a real question?  I realize my question is unlike most questions that are posted, but I feel my question relates to English Language & Usage, shows some research effort, and could be useful.

Comment: That would be the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq); I could see where some might regard this as a "chatty, open-ended" question. _Of course_ a dictionary is a better place to learn about suitable antonyms than an Ngram. Your Ngram is interesting, and provides some measure of evidence that _tiny_ & _huge_ could be coupled, much like _small_ & _large_ are, but [that won't always work](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=love%2Chate&year_start=1800). So, there's not much to say here except, "Hmm, that's interesting," and, "Yes, dictionaries & thesauri are the best resources."

Comment: Choosing an antonym by frequency rather than context won't always work. Every word has connotations & denotations that have to be considered. Sometimes the obvious antonyms don't work because the style or register is wrong. Sometimes certain contexts demand certain pairs of words in opposition. I often decide that a standard antonym doesn't work in a specific sentence in the articles I edit every day. The four examples you've chosen don't need an Ngram to help you decide. The result was predictable to anyone who reads extensively.

Comment: There's also a matter of polling. Considering your question: *I'm wondering whether anyone has looked at* the only direct answers would be "I did", "I didn't", and "I know someone who did".  These are rather of dubious value. A question "Best method to find closest antonyms?" would be much better - with your idea given as your research outside of the common dictionary comparison, and one could expect other good ideas for this.

Comment: @SF. Your comment is helpful.  I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: @BillFranke: I must agree. Direct antonym to "Short" would be "Long", but then when you're talking about a person, choosing the direct antonym would be plain wrong. The context dictates to use "Tall" and while strongly secondary, this is the antonym to choose here.

Comment: @BillFranke [link](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+tall%2C+he+short&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) Is a possible way of incorporating context into the search technique, and I appreciate your comment.  I certainly agree that the method will not work in all cases.

Comment: Interesting. You might want to run some tests with unusual pairs to see whether the method is actually helpful. Let us know.

Comment: @J.R. [Love and hate](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+loves%2Che+hates%2Che+dislikes%2Che+detests%2Che+abhors%2Che+despises&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) If we use Bill's suggestion to correct for context, I think we see that hate is closer to love in frequency and time-series correlation than some other possible antonyms that came to my mind.  Also, thank you for pointing out a weakness of my method.  Seeing the flaws is helpful in improving the method.

Comment: True. Adding words like "he is" to the Ngram will certainly help, as that will do more than count mere words. However, as you point out, the method still isn't foolproof: [here's an example](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+is+foolish%2Che+is+wise&year_start=1800), using "he is foolish" and "he is wise." [Here's another](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+love+you%2CI+hate+you&year_start=1800); compared with the first Ngram, notice how "I love you" is on the rise as wisdom starts to decline. Evidence that love makes fools out of all of us? ;^)

Comment: While we're on the subject, try [war and peace](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=war%2Cpeace&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0).

Comment: As fun a question as this is, it is not very constructive. It's eliciting a discussion about opinions. On SE, chat seems the most appropriate place, but that's too chaotic to expect a coherent discussion (but you should try). If only alt.usage.englsih were still around.

Comment: @Mitch When you state the question is not very constructive, should I take that to mean you do not believe the answers provided here are useful?  And that this forum favors clear-cut answers to thoughtful discussions?  While I agree opinions are being offered, are opinions not an important part of the English language and its usage?  While five moderators do not believe this post served a purpose, I found the comments by Bill and J.R. both thoughtful and useful in refining my method.  In closing, while I fail to agree with your decision, I respect it and appreciate your maintaining this forum

Comment: @philq02: 'Not Constructive' can mean lots of things, but here it means that your are eliciting a discussion about a technique. A natural reaction is that 'where else would one talk about such a thing than something called ELU?'. But unfortunately the structure of this site is specifically directed towards not allowing discussions. As to opinions, again, it's just the nature of this site to disparage opinions and opinion-asking questions. It would be great fir there to be a place for all of this but unfortunately ELU is not it. Check out related posts on meta, it might help understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Nice method!. 
The only issue I keep finding is that as the graph comes near the present, the differences between the words seem really scarce. (use the examples I give)
It seems like in the past there were more clear differences between: stature and height: or distance and length.
Or maybe is just me?